# Window 10 Pro product key not accepted: “Some of these characters can't appear in the product key.”

Tags: windows-activation

I cloned a drive from my "planned to retire" PC that has Windows 10 Home, and installed the cloned drive to a new computer. I also have the Windows 10 Pro DVD pack and opened it up to use the new product key on my new computer, thus upgrading from Home to Professional.

Unfortunately Windows isn't accepting the code and I have this message

> "Some of these characters can't appear in the product key."

Stuck here since.

Contemplating on seeking assistance on Windows Activation team but they might trace it to my retired PC. Reformatting & reinstalling is not an option as there's so many apps, setting, profiles and other stuff in the drive. Which is why I used cloning to so my drive (and by new computer) and get off and running right away.

Answer (score 14):

> I cloned a drive from my "planned to retire" PC that has Windows 10 Home, and installed the cloned drive to a new computer

Windows OEM licenses cannot be transferred to a new machine.

> I also have the Windows 10 Pro DVD pack and opened it up to use the new product key on my new computer, thus upgrading from Home to Professional.

Run the following elevated commands to remove all traces of the OEM license from your cloned HDD.

1. `slmgr /upk`
2. `slmgr /cpky`

Then run the following elevated command

1. `slmgr /ipk product key number`

You can use `YTMG3-N6DKC-DKB77-7M9GH-8HVX7` to perform the upgrade, after a reboot, repeat the commands then use your actual product key.

> Unfortunately Windows isn't accepting the code and I have this message

You need to avoid using those illegal characters (A, E, I, L, N, O, S, U, and Z) and (0, 1 and 5)

Source: [Activation error: 0xC004F050](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/activation-error-0xc004f050/dfbda045-b480-43c9-8f1e-6b6c9ea0f53c)